# On INSERT, changes() sometimes returns 1 even if row already existed

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE UniqueFile (
    filePath TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    created INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (strftime('%s', 'now'))
)
```

which along with SQLite's `changes()` function I use to determine if file entry is inserted for the first time or not:

```
fun insertFilePath(filePath : String) : Boolean {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO UniqueFile (filePath) VALUES(?)", arrayOf(filePath)) // This will silently hide any other errors. Better alternative is `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, however it requires SQLite 3.24.0+

        val cursor = db.rawQuery("select changes()", null)
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        val changes = cursor.getInt(0)
        cursor.close()

        if (changes > 0) {
            LogHelper.log(this, "Inserted UNIQUE filePath: $filePath, changes: $changes")
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Sometimes `changes()` returns `1` even for existing entry.

```
First: [2022-07-12 08:27:26]: Inserted UNIQUE filePath: /storage/emulated/0/somefile.jpg
Second: [2022-07-12 08:28:32]: Inserted UNIQUE filePath: /storage/emulated/0/somefile.jpg
```

`created` field is set to `1657614446` which translates to 08:27:26. It's like second INSERT was at 08:28:32, but it wasn't as there is no duplicate. Yet `changes()` returned 1.

There is no other function which reads/deletes/writes to this table, however there may be multiple threads opening connections to database. I use singleton approach to make sure only one database connection is open at a time.

```
class DatabaseHandler private constructor(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {

        private var instance: DatabaseHandler? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context) : DatabaseHandler {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = DatabaseHandler(context)             
            }

            return instance as DatabaseHandler
        }
}
```

How could this happen? I would happily get rid of `INSERT OR IGNORE` but need to support devices with SQLite not supporting `ON DUPLICATE` clause.

Comment: Why don't you use the insert() method: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)?

Comment: @forpas Actually `insert` worked well, but was throwing constraint exceptions. Once replaced with: `insertWithOnConflict` works flawlessly. It's great that Android API can make up some feature lacking natively in that SQLite version.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to [native insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)). I have no clue why `changes()` erroneously returns 1 sometimes.

```
fun insertFilePath(filePath : String) : Boolean {
    val db = this.writableDatabase

    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put("filePath", filePath)
        
    // Classic `insert` function was throwing SQLiteConstraintException errors
    val rowId = db.insertWithOnConflict("Files", null, values, CONFLICT_IGNORE)

    if (rowId != -1L) {
        LogHelper.log(this, "Inserted UNIQUE filePath: $filePath, rowId: $rowId")
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```